# Reset input values respective to new elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a modal window with an accordion inside where the user can change some values about that image. I'm sharing one modal and accordion for all the images on the page.

What is happening is that when I change the value for one image to, for example, true, that true value is also being shown in the accordion for all other images as well.

What I would like to see is for only the true value to be shown for the image it was actually changed on.

This is the JavaScript so far:

```
  $(".glyphicon-tags").on('click', function(){
    var iid = $(this).data('iid');

    $(".onoffswitch").off("click").on("click", function(){
      var tid = $(this).data('tid');
        alert(iid + ' => ' + tid);
    });
  });
```

**EDIT:**
This is the HTML that is being generated for each image on the page.

```
<span class="footer-right">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tags" data-toggle="modal" data-iid="MYIMAGEIDHERE" data-target="#modal"></span>
</span>
```

This is the switch that is being generated from my backend code:

```
  <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch onoffswitch-checkbox" id="HEADERID" data-tid="MYTAGID">
  <label class="onoffswitch onoffswitch-label" for="HEADERID">
    <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
    <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
  </label>
```

**EDIT:**

This is what the JavaScript looks like now. Please notice that this includes the tagID and the imageID. When the user clicks on a checkbox, the imageID and the tagID are sent to the server. This sets the tag for that image.

To recap, I am using one copy of dynamically generated inputs from my backend code that serve ALL of the images on the page. The issues I see with this are that on pageload (a new session), it is making it impossible for me to re-set what the user previously tagged, and the last issue is that when a user tags for example, image #1, the value for image #1 also shows (checked) for all future image he tags (during that session).

```
  $(".glyphicon-tags").on('click', function(e){
    var iid = $(this).data('iid'); // This is the imageID
    e.preventDefault();

    $(".onoffswitch").off("click").on("click", function(){
      var tid = $(this).data('tid'); // This is the tagID

      if( typeof $(this).prop('checked') !== 'undefined'){
        var request = $.ajax({
          url : "tag.php",
          type: "POST",
          data:{iid: iid, tid: tid}
        });
      }
    });
  });
```

Comment: can you show the HTML as well please? I'm guessing maybe you have multiple instances of glyphicon-tags and then multiple instances of onoffswitch which you regard as being associated with a specific instance of glyphicon-tags? However your code takes no account of such an association. How are the two things linked? I'm assuming "true" in your example is the value of `iid` in your code?

Comment: I do have multiple iterations of onoffswitch. Each onoffswitch should be unique to that image. That is to say that whatever value was changed on one image shouldn't propagate to the other images. Sure, ADyson, I'll post the HTML as well. And thank you very much for helping me.

Comment: ok so in that case I think you need to target your event handler at the specific instance of the onoffswitch which relates to the clicked image. For that you need some way, via the markup, to identify the correct one. Once you post the HTML it'll be easier to make a suggestion.

Comment: OK, great. I think I should be able to identify it by the image ID `iid`. I'll post it now.

Comment: what about the switches? Where are they in the markup, in comparison and what do they look like?

Comment: OK, sorry, I'll post that as well up top

Comment: Thanks. Will it be possible to change the markup so the onoffswitch can have the `data-iid="MYIMAGEIDHERE"` property on it as well, so we can match it to the image tag?

Comment: Bear with me, ADyson, I'm looking in the backend code to see if it's available. Not to hold you up, let's assume that I can also get the imageID in there as well. Can we get a solution using the imageID?

Comment: Actually, I just read the code and no, there is no way, at that point in the code to get the imageID. The reason being is that the accordion is being dynamically built for the HTML, BEFORE any image is selected.

Comment: `$('.onoffswitch[data-iid=" + iid +"]').off`...etc I think, off the top of my head. Hmm. I would guess if the code loops to generate the images, then switches are surely generated as part of a loop which also creates the image, otherwise how does it know how many switches to make?

Comment: The thing is, I'm not building a modal with accordion for each image. In my case, the tags are built first and then included in the HTML for the user to use against all images. I hope that makes sense. Is there a way to reset the onoffswitch so that the switch shows off? This is an ugly hack but if I'm understanding what you want to do here, I'd have to build a modal and accordion for each image.

Comment: @ADyson, actually... Can't we somehow use the imageID from the `span` tag? It has the `data-iid`.

Comment: Ok I misunderstood the question completely. I thought the "true" value you were referring to was something to do with `iid`. But you just mean whether the switch is on or off...and it needs resetting to the correct value each time you change the image being displayed? So you need a way to store that state for the particular image, each time you close the modal, I think, and restore it again when re-opening. I need to go home now but will have a think, if you don't manage to fix it in the meantime.

Comment: No problem. I really do appreciate the help here. So to clarify the behavior that I want to change is to have the accordion value reflect the true value for that image. So, if imageID 100 was changed to true, then imageID 101 should not show true, but rather false. The way it is working now, if I change the value for imageID 100 to true, **all** images are showing true. This isn't right. If imageID 100 is true and all other images have no changes, then the accordion should only show imageID 100 as a true value. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: @ADyson, I just noticed that the imageID is already in the `.glyphicon-tags` click function. If you look at the 1st snippet of code above, you'll see it there. Can't I use that? It's just above the `.onoffswitch` where you said you wanted it.

Comment: yeah I guess you could. I think what you really need to be doing is using that as an index to store the state of the switch for that image. So a JavaScript data structure where for image ID1, the on-off switch is true, and false for ID 2 etc. Then you can use that to correctly set the state of the button whenever you select a different image from the accordion, or whenever the button itself is changed. Does that makes sense?
 Do you need an example? Also presumably at some point you send this data to the server to save it (otherwise what would be the point?) - have you implemented that yet?

Comment: @ADyson, Hi ADyson, sorry for the delay. Yes, it makes perfect sense. I'm not a JavaScript guy, so it would be greatly appreciated if you could provide an example for me to go by. Saving the state of the switchID and the imageID is certainly the way to go. Just for clarification, the values are already being saved with AJAX when the user clicks one of the switches.

Comment: well it would give me a head start if you'd share that bit of code which does the ajax saving. It would make sense to combine that with saving the state within the Javascript - thanks. Although, what you _could_ do is restore the state from the server via another ajax call?

Comment: @ADyson, that sounds like a good idea too. I think I have a couple issues going on here. Let me just point out something else that I thought of last night. Each user should be able to see what tag they used for each image. Because the tags are being dynamically built with my backend code, and because there is only **one** panel of checkboxes for **all** images, I'm not sure how to do this. I thought about using an AJAX call per image to get the vals, but not sure if that's the best way to go or not. I'm really lost on this issue. I appreciate the help. Will post more code above. Thanks!

Comment: an ajax call which loads the data per image whenever the user causes the modal to be displayed is fairly standard. The modal then gets populated with the latest values from the server which pertain to that image. Then the user can save those values back to the server via ajax, and the modal is closed. Just like if you opened a form on the desktop, or in a standalone web form - the main difference being the use of ajax, and the lack of need for a full page refresh.

Comment: @ADyson, I think this is exactly what I need. Thank you for putting this into prospective for me, ADyson. If you wouldn't mind, can you post this as the answer and I'll credit you for it? Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An ajax call which restores the data for an image into the modal whenever the user causes the modal to be displayed is a fairly standard way to do this. You are already saving the data to the server when the modal is saved, so it makes sense to use this data to re-populate the modal if the same image is selected again later.

That way the modal then gets populated with the latest values from the server which pertain to that image. Then the user can save those values back to the server via ajax again, and the modal is closed. Just like if you opened a form on the desktop, or in a standalone web form - the main difference being the use of ajax, and the lack of need for a full page refresh.